# order/sort by a field in database

Tags: php, database

Hi would it be possible to sort the records on agestart field when displayed in the webpage.
This is the code it works ok but I can;t get it to sort.

```
case 'lookagestart':
    $data = $osDB->getAll ( $sqlSelect.$same_lookagestartsql, array( USER_TABLE, $user['username'], $user['lookagestart'],'active',$active_lang ) ) ;
    $t->assign('showhead',get_lang('above_lookagestart'));

    break;
```

Comment: Looks like you're using an ORM. Which ORM are you using?

Comment: Hi, Sorry I wouldn't know for sure still trying to learn php with adjusting some code from a excisting script. But if I am correct it is adodb. Otherwise I can't tell you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to your system, I won't know for sure but...

What if you tried this?

```
case 'lookagestart':
    $sort_clause = ' ORDER BY `lookagestart` ';
    $data = $osDB->getAll ( $sqlSelect.$same_lookagestartsql.$sort_clause, array( USER_TABLE, $user['username'], $user['lookagestart'],'active',$active_lang ) ) ;
    $t->assign('showhead',get_lang('above_lookagestart'));

    break;
```

Comment: Woww you solved it. Was struggling where to add the order by for some reason it never sorted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I figured it out by looking at the variables `$sqlSelect` and `$same_lookagestartsql` which contained the word "sql". Typically systems pass SQL as a string. It's always easier with a second pair of eyes :)

Comment: Also note that I put spaces around the clause I added  :)